# How to get rid of unmanaged code in VW 3.1d and ENVY

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

I have an old VW3/ENVY image with a parcel loaded as unmanaged code (exactly the situation [Mastering ENVY/DEVELOPER](http://books.google.com/books?id=LzFavf682p4C&lpg=PA156&ots=30NkMNUv40&dq=envy%20unmanaged%20code&pg=PA156#v=onepage&q=%22do%20not%20load%20parcelled%20versions%22&f=false) warns against). Unfortunately, this problem happened a long time ago and it's too late to just "go back" to an image without the parcel loaded.

Apparently, there is a way to solve this problem (we have one development image where this has been solved, and there are normal configuration maps that contain the exact same code as the unmanaged parcel but they can't be loaded), but the exact way has long since been forgotten (and there are some problems with taking that particular dev image as the base for a new runtime image, so I need to find out how how to do it again).

In theory, it should be possible to remove the parcel and reload the code from a configuration map. In practice, all normal ways (using the ParcelBrowser or directly calling UnmanagedCode>>remove) fail. I even tried manually removing the offending selectors from the method dictionary, but past a certain point (involving a call to #primBecome:) the whole image hangs completely (I can't even drop into the debugger). I started hacking the instances of the classes and methods, hoping I'd trick ENVY into thinking that these particular methods are normal versioned code, but without any success yet.

Are there any smalltalk/envy gurus around that still remember enough of VW 3 to provide me with any pointers?

**Status update**
After a week of trying to solve the problem I finally made it, at least partially, so in case anyone's interested...

First, I had to fix file pointers for the umnanaged code (otherwise, all everything that tried to touch the methods would throw an exception). It looks like ENVY extends Parcel so that, in theory, all integer file pointers are changed to ENVY's `void` filepointer when loaded, but in my case, I had to do it manually (a Parcel provides enumeration for all selectors it defines). Another way would be to tweak the `filePointer` code, but that can't easily be done automatically on every image where it's needed.

Then, the parcel can be discarded, which drops the parcel information, but keeps the code. The official "Discard" mechanism needs to have a valid changes file (which envy doesn't use so it has to be set manually, and reset afterwards) and the parcel source (which we fortunately had).

To be able to make any changes to the methods (either manually, or via loading an application or class from ENVY), they need to get rid of their unmanaged status. This can be done by manually tweaking `TheClass>>applicationAssocs` (I also got rid of all references to the classes in UnmanagedCode sich as timestamps, and removed the reference to the discarded parcel). I actually had some info on how to get to this point from my boss, but I haven't been able to understand the instructions until I almost figured it out by myself.

This finally allowed me to load and reload all the Applications that contained the classes. In theory. In practice, the image still hung completely whenever I tried to load a newer version of the Application (that contained the code formerly in the parcel).

It turned out that the crashes had absolutely *nothing to do with the code being unmanaged*, but with the fact that the parcel in question modified `InputState>>process:`, where it caused an exception due to a missing and/or uninitialized class variable (the `InputState>>initialize` method wasn't called until after the new `process:` method was in place). I had to modify the `Notifier` class to dump all exceptions to a file to find out what was going on. Adding the class variable to the source of the class (instead of adding it via reflection), suspending the input processing thread via `toBeLoadedCode` and starting it again in the `loaded` method and creating a new version of the application solved even this problem.

Now everything works, in theory. In practice it's still unusable, because reloading the WindowSystem or VisualworksBase applications causes their initialization blocks to run, and a whole lot of settings are reset to their defaults - fonts and font sizes, window colors, UI settings... And there doesn't seem to be any way to just save the settings to a file and load them later on, or just to see what all the settings are (either the official Settings menu doesn't show everything, or we have a heavily tweaked image... so much for reconstructing it from scratch). But that's a completely different question.

Comment: +1 wow, haven't seen any smalltalk tagged questions in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, normally the recommendation would be that you should be able to rebuild your development image from scratch by loading your code from the repository. But if you had that, then the answer would be simple, just discard that image and reload. I think it's been long enough that I've lost whatever knowledge I've had about how to mess with the internal structures to get it back, and it sounds like you've tried a lot of things. So, although it might be painful, figuring out the recipe to rebuild your development image by loading stuff from the repository sounds like it may be your best bet. It probably isn't all that horrible, there just might be a few dependencies on the image state, or special doits that need to be executed.

You also probably need to validate what's in the repository against what's in the image you're working from. If there was unmanaged code loaded and then someone modified it and saved it, it's not clear to me that it would have been saved to ENVY. So you probably want to audit everything that was unmanaged code and if it's been changed, save that to a repository edition.

Sorry I don't have any better answers.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer! I've been able to make some progress, and it turned out that the actual unmanaged code was the least of my problems. I'll update my original question with my findings.